# What are the advantages/disadvantages of YSlow over Speed Tracer?

Tags: performance

I've used YSlow add in for Firefox and found it useful, does the new new google addin for Chrome give me anything extra?

http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/faster-apps-for-faster-web-introducing.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool for Chrome seems to offer a lot more detail, but on the other hand the finest details only apply to Chrome, in other browsers the details will not be the same. YSlow is more of a general tool offering guidelines based on known problems. Even if the tool for Chrome shows a lot of detail, it doesn't seem to offer much suggestions on what to do about any problems.